# searching a specific issue type within an issuelink jira

Tags: jira, jql

I am using jira and I am trying to find features and enablers which have the issuelinktype "relates to" however within this I am trying to narrow down those that have the above issuelinktype but those linked issues are of the Objective issue type.

below is some pseudo-query
SELECT * feature

WHERE issuelinktype="relates to"

AND issue link type target = "objective"

I have tried applying in statements and other traditional SQL syntax however these do not appear within JQL
I also have not tried any plug ins or other API's that could attach to Jira as I do not have access to them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the query:

```
issueFunction in linkedIssuesOfAll("subquery", "relates to") And type = "objective"
```

The subquery is related to the linked issue with the link (if you write in the subquery "type = Epic" it will return all the issues that have linktype "relates to" to Epics").
The rest of the query is for the issue that you want the query return.

Comment: Hi unfortunately issue function is a scriptrunner only piece of JQL which I don't have access to